# Label doesn't appear in menu item angular

Tags: angular, angular8, primeng, menuitem, angular-services

I use primeng and angular. I create a service that return a string when un hash is passed like parameter:

```
//this.propertiesName is and Object with all property that i need and this is just calculated read a json file
     getValueFromProperties(hash: string): string {
        return this.propertiesName[id];
      }
```

the service works when I try to access a property it return me value.But when I create MenuItem:

```
 items: MenuItem[];
...
this.items = [
      {
        label: this.propertiesNameService.getValueFromProperties('home'),//Here is empty also if 'home' is a property with value
      },

      }
```

So  the text in empty, i can't read this:

my html page is:

```
<p-menubar [model]="items" >

</p-menubar>
```

the json file is:

```
{
    "dog": "dog",
    "home": "Home",
}
```

Anyone can help to understand why the label is empty?

Comment: Here you are passing id : `return this.propertiesName[id];` I think it should be  `return this.propertiesName[hash];`

Comment: Your getValueFromProperties function is wired. Your function arg is named hash and you use id. Id should be undefined and you are returning an undefined porperty string

Answer (score 0):

where is id properties ? Function accepts 'hash' properties
this.propertiesName[id]; => this.propertiesName[hash]